# neo4j: backup and restore data

Tags: neo4j

I have a single node neo4j instance(redhat OS based VM) running.
Any easier way to backup data and export it to neo4j instance running in another VM?

I tried zipping the data/database/neo4j folder on source VM and unzipping it on destination VM. But, getting errors while starting neo4j.

> java.lang.RuntimeException: Mismatching store id. Store StoreId:
> StoreId{creationTime=1676271868772, randomId=5465786452791406693,
> storeVersion=3471768636287762695, upgradeTime=1676271868772,
> upgradeTxId=1}. Transaction log StoreId:
> StoreId{creationTime=1683789569809, randomId=-7569579037412136217,
> storeVersion=3471768636287762695, upgradeTime=1683789569809,
> upgradeTxId=1}

Any thoughts/other approaches are welcome!

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `dump` command of the `neo4j-admin` command-line interface. Make sure that your database is offline before running this command. The command is like this:

```
neo4j-admin database dump <database-name>
```

This will create a .dump file. This will be created in the folder pointed by the setting `server.directories.dumps.root`.

For more options, you can refer to this [documentation](https://neo4j.com/docs/operations-manual/current/backup-restore/offline-backup/).

Similarly, you restore this dump using the command `neo4j-admin database load`. Here's the documentation for the [load](https://neo4j.com/docs/operations-manual/current/backup-restore/restore-dump/) command.

Alternatively, if you want to back up the data while it is online, use the command `neo4j-admin database backup`. This command generates a bunch of files known as `artifacts`, which can be combined to form one single artifact file using the command `neo4j-admin database aggregate-backup`. To restore these artifacts files use the command `neo4j-admin database restore`.

Refer to these documentations:

[Online Backup](https://neo4j.com/docs/operations-manual/current/backup-restore/online-backup/)

[Aggregate backup chains](https://neo4j.com/docs/operations-manual/current/backup-restore/aggregate/)

[Restore Backup](https://neo4j.com/docs/operations-manual/current/backup-restore/restore-backup/)